# copula - definition

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

I'm following some lecture notes about copulas and the definition is confusing me. I think I understand what copulas is when I read about copulas using other literature, but I also want to understand this definition. The definition is:

If a random vector $X = (X_1,...,X_d)$ with multivariate c.d.f. $F_X$ has continuous marginals $F_1, ... ,F_d$ where $F_i(x_i) = P(X_i < x_i)$, then the random vector

\begin{equation}
(F_1(X_1), ... ,F_d(X_d))
\end{equation}

has uniform marginals and hence its distribution $C$ is a copula satisfying

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3.1} F _ { \mathrm { \color{blue} X } } \left( x _ { 1 } , \ldots , x _ { d } \right) = C \left( F _ { 1 } \left( x _ { 1 } \right) , \ldots , F _ { d } \left( x _ { d } \right) \right)\end{equation}

Is the random vector I denoted with $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ referring to 
$$(X_1,...,X_d)$$ 
or
$$(F_1(X_1), ... ,F_d(X_d))$$

I think it should be the last one, but the notation is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The random vector I denoted with $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ refers to $$(X_1,...,X_d).$$ This follows by;

$$\begin{aligned} F _ { X } \left( x _ { 1 } , ..., x _ { d } \right) & = \operatorname { Pr } \left[ X _ { 1 } \leq x _ { 1 } , ... , X _ { d } \leq x _ { d } \right] \\ & = \operatorname { Pr } \left[ F _ { 1 } \left( X _ { 1 } \right) \leq F _ { 1 } \left( x _ { 1 } \right) , ..., F _ { d } \left( X _ { d } \right) \leq F _ { d } \left( x _ { d } \right) \right] \\ & = C \left( F _ { 1 } \left( x _ { 1 } \right) , ..., F _ { d } \left( x _ { d } \right) \right) \end{aligned}$$

where we in the last inequality used the definition of a copula.